# Dynamic script for closing bootstrap modal in WordPress Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-modal

I have some HTML code which displays 3 videos and a script to stop the video when the modal is closed.

HTML code

```
<!-- Grid row -->
<div class="row">

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">

    <!--Modal: Name-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

          <!--Body-->
          <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">

            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A3PDXmYoF5U"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

          </div>

          <!--Footer-->
          <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
            <span class="mr-4">Spread the word!</span>
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-fb"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <!--Twitter-->
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-tw"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <!--Google +-->
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-gplus"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
            <!--Linkedin-->
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-ins"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded btn-md ml-4" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal: Name-->

    <a><img class="img-fluid z-depth-1" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/screens/yt/screen-video-1.jpg" alt="video"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1"></a>

  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">

    <!--Modal: Name-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

          <!--Body-->
          <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">

            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wTcNtgA6gHs"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

          </div>

          <!--Footer-->
          <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
            <span class="mr-4">Spread the word!</span>
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-fb"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <!--Twitter-->
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-tw"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <!--Google +-->
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-gplus"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
            <!--Linkedin-->
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-ins"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded btn-md ml-4" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal: Name-->

    <a><img class="img-fluid z-depth-1" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/screens/yt/screen-video-2.jpg" alt="video"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal6"></a>

  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">

    <!--Modal: Name-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

          <!--Body-->
          <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">

            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vlDzYIIOYmM"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

          </div>

          <!--Footer-->
          <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
            <span class="mr-4">Spread the word!</span>
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-fb"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <!--Twitter-->
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-tw"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <!--Google +-->
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-gplus"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
            <!--Linkedin-->
            <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-ins"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded btn-md ml-4" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal: Name-->

    <a><img class="img-fluid z-depth-1" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/screens/yt/screen-video-3.jpg" alt="video"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal4"></a>

  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

</div>
<!-- Grid row -->
```

Script:

```
$('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  $('#modal1 iframe').attr("src", $("#modal1 iframe").attr("src"));
});

$('#modal6').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  $('#modal6 iframe').attr("src", $("#modal6 iframe").attr("src"));
});

$('#modal4').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  $('#modal4 iframe').attr("src", $("#modal4 iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

I am able to display these videos but once the modal is closed the script should generate dynamically when a new video is added. In a word, I want to make the script dynamic. Kindly help me with this.